# Сервис медленно работает на iis

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, публикация-приложений

прошу помощи по выявлению причины медленной работы сервиса, запущенного на IIS 10.0 сервере.
Случалось ли у вас так, что вроде бы быстро работающий сайт, который мгновенно подгружает страницы на локальном хостинге, перестает быстро работать при публикации на IIS? В итоге запросы к серверу могут задерживаться на 10-15с., что никуда не годится. В свою очередь, на IIS вертятся другие проекты, которые в основном не отличаются (по настройкам) от моего текущего и работают достаточно быстро.
Сам сервис является простенькой страничкой с выгруженными данными из бд на MS SQL. Также присутствует авторизация с помощью Active Directory.

---

На данный момент я пытался сделать:

1. Заливал на IIS стандартный asp.net mvc проект.
2. У рабочего проекта менял директорию на мой текущий сервис.

В обоих случаях сайт все равно работал очень медленно.

Comment: Я так полагаю что где-то в самом сайте происходит циклическая ошибка, которая естественно подавляется (не отображается) на сервере релиза, но при этом запускает весь механизм логгирования. Что по сути и создает кучу записей в лог (от туда и торможение), но при этом вы её не видите. Стоит проверить логи сайта, на предмет таких ошибок или если это невозможно, проверить все for, while ... методом их отключения и проверять уже какой из модулей сайта подвешивает сайт.

Comment: Кстати да, а добавьте логирование в ключевых местах кода, это довольно просто. Будете точно знать, где именно тормоза происходят, а где быстро выполняется.